# Android - How can my Activity detect that I received a notification in Firebase Messaging Service?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, foreground

let me discuss with you a scenario, let the app be in the foreground with Activity "X" opened. Now my app received a notification through Firebase Messaging Service.
What I want? 
I want that if my app is in the foreground, my activity "X" could detect if I received a notification so that I could switch an icon.

Here's my code for the Firebase Messaging Service:

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message){
    type=message.getData().get("type");
    CrucialData.setReceivedNotificationWithoutChecking(true);
    createNotification(message);
}

private void createNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    checkingIfAppIsInForeground(context);
    if(!inForeground){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
                .setContentTitle("Your chat is going to expire tomorrow!")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, main_activity.class);

        resultIntent.putExtra("launchedFromNotification",true);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your app to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(main_activity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mNotificationId is a unique integer your app uses to identify the
        mNotificationManager.notify(1231, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Local Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to communicate between your service and activity.

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/4244598).

Comment: Local Broadcast is deprecated any other good and proper way of implementation